# In UWP WinRt, How to insert an Image in an existing PDF page

Tags: image, pdf, uwp, insert, winrt-component

I'm looking for a solution to insert an images in a PDF file from UWP app.

I need to create a new pdf with images stamped on the PDF file (without distorting PDF quality) and export it to the user.

Currently i'm printing the document which distorts the PDF export Quality.

Please suggest some useful reference.

I tried to begin with iText library, but it is not supported in UWP app.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: As a new member of Stack Overflow you probably shpuld have read the introductory [tour]. Library recommendations are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow as they tend to run into opiniated discussions and attract spam.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for the update. I've re-phrased the ask.

Comment: @ShivTyagi recommendations for 3rd party libraries can be asked here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/